# Replace a value in a list in a JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json

I want to change the value of an element in a list in a JSON file. The function should change the value `"x"` in the "CarIds" item to a input string, `"abc"`, as an example. I saw some examples changing the value, but I can't seem to be able to change the value in a list.

Here is my JSON file.

```
{
    "CarIds": [
        "x"
    ],
    "Tariff": {
        "currency": "CAD",
        "countryCode": "CA",
    }
}
```

Here is the python function trying to accomplish this.

```
import json

with open('./data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
        
for item in data['CarIds']:
    item['CarIds'] = item['CarIds'].replace('"x"', "abc")

with open('./new-data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```

I keep on getting *TypeError: string indices must be integers*

Comment: `data['CarIds'][0] = "abc"` .  CarIds is just a normal list.  Or, `data['CarIds'] = [s.replace('x','abc') for s in data['CarIds']]`.  Remember that the quotes don't actually exist in the data elements.

Comment: The item assignment does not seem to work, but using replace it works, thanks Tim.

Comment: Based on the json you have supplied, the simple assignment should work fine. https://tio.run/##TY4xC4MwEIX3@xXhlihIKXQrdCh26d5NMqRGqdImconQIP72NCZDvenuve/u3uTdy@hTCMNnMuTYaI0GGK0jdmGc8wVYLKwl3ZXFM2vSnLQvpl5UGXlIGvo@IssfaWeiTrc@qlhfb1jtLDNrR742qstuvrbCCvEtKOlkTLDFObyNVLbYMpUw0aBdsbklJKjhORsXzVHEDZTPFvdYCD8

Comment: btw, `.replace('"x"', "abc")`... there **is not `'"x"'` in the car ids list, there is an `'x'` though

Comment: also, the example you posted is not valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

`data["carIds"]` is a list with a single value `["x"]`. Just replace that first element

```
import json

with open('./data.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
       
data['CarIds'][0] = "abc"

with open('./new-data.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```

Comment: This gives me a TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment. Tim's answer using replace() works, though.

Comment: @DaveWhyte - I had to fix a bug in your JSON data (a trailing comma) and then ran this code successfully. The error suggests that your data is actually `"carIds":"x"` (a string not a list of strings). In that case, Tim's replace would kindof work by converting `"x"` to `["abc"]` but replacing a string with a list of strings seems odd in itself.